# how to load interstitial ads correctly?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I have written code to show interstitial ads in my android app. Its working fine but the problem is that ads are popping up so much. What could be the problem?? is it the same way user will see the ads too frequently?

MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

            private ViewPager viewPager;
            private DrawerLayout drawer;
            private TabLayout tabLayout;
            private String[] pageTitle = {"fragment1", "fragment2","Fragment3"};

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
                mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));
                AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed()
                    {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                .build();
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
                });
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);
                viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
                viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                AppRate.with(this)
                        .setInstallDays(0)
                        .setLaunchTimes(3)
                        .setRemindInterval(2)
                        .monitor();

                AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this);
                AppRate.with(this).clearAgreeShowDialog();

                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();

                tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitle[i]));
                }

                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                assert navigationView != null;
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
                navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

                ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

                viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

                tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.fr1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                } else if (id == R.id.fr2) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }else if (id == R.id.fr3) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                }

                else if (id == R.id.Suggestion) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Suggestion.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (id == R.id.Logic) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, logicBehind.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (id == R.id.close) {
                    finish();
                }

                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                boolean wentBack = false;

                if (Fragment1.canGoBack()) {
                    wentBack = true;
                    Fragment1.goBack();
                }
                if (Fragment2.canGoBack()) {
                    wentBack = true;
                    Fragment2.goBack();
                }
                if (Fragment3.canGoBack()) {
                    wentBack = true;
                    Fragment3.goBack();
                }


                if (!wentBack) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Exit app")
                            .setMessage("Do you want to exit the app?")
                            .setIcon(R.mipmap.mainlogo)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> super.onBackPressed())
                            .setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {})
                            .show();
                }
            }


            @Override
               public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


           }

        }
```

This is what I have tried. The code for the Interstitial ad is added in the onCreate method of MainActivity.java.

Comment: That depends on how many times loadAd is getting called. You need to check where you've placed this logic and how its getting executed.

Comment: @CoderP I have placed this logic as it is in the onCreate method of MainActivity.java but still its loading too fast. is it because i am using test ad ID??

Comment: I am using test ad ID maybe that could be the reason?? because the demo ad is already loaded up

Comment: The issue is that its loading too fast or that it multiple ads are loading up? If the logic is in onCreate ... ad will pop up as soon as the activity is created.

Comment: ads are loading up too fast that is the issue. When I close the ad using the cross button next ad loads up within 4-5 seconds although all are demo ads(Provided by google admob) as i am using test ad ID of admob

Comment: It has nothing to do with demo ads, the behavior will be same on prod too. Can you share your activity code?

Comment: @CodePI have added in the post.

Comment: That's because you are calling ad.load in ad.close() so as soon as you close your ad , the next ad loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed()
                    {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                .build();
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
                });
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);
```

As per the code that you've written, you call loadAd() in adClose(). So when you click on cross, the next ad is loaded. and you've called ad.show() in onAdLoaded. So as soon as the ad loads, it shows.. so this is like a continuous loop, the next ad will show on every ad closed.

Comment: So how can i fix this issue?? can please you guide me?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to show only one interstitial, then remove all logic from onClose function. If you want to show ads periodically say after 2 mins of closing an ad, then start a timer on adClose() and call loadAd() inside the timer when timer completes. So the logic will depend on what you want to achieve or how you want to show ads.

Comment: P.S. Its a bad practice to show multiple interstitial ads. It accounts for a frustrating user experience. So use it judiciously.

Comment: yes, I too don't want to make the user should feel frustrated that is why I asked you for help. thanks, buddy

Comment: If your doubt is resolved, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: done brother :) one more question-is it legal to show the ads let's say after 4-5mins? or is it illegal?

Comment: Yes, It's legal. And hey! I am a sister :) LOL